# error: forward declaration of struct

Tags: c++, oop, forward-declaration

I'm receiving the error:

```
proprietario.cpp:36: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Motocicleta’
proprietario.h:12: error: forward declaration of ‘struct Motocicleta’
```

Motocicleta.h:

```
#ifndef __MOTOCICLETA__
#define __MOTOCICLETA__
#include <iostream>
#include "veiculo.h"
#include "proprietario.h"
using namespace std;
class Proprietario;
class Motocicleta:public Veiculo{

public:
  Motocicleta(int nPassageiros, string modelo, string placa, int aFabricacao, Proprietario* pai, int nRodas, int aro);
  ~Motocicleta();
  Motocicleta (const Motocicleta& source);
  Motocicleta& operator= (const Motocicleta& source);

  string toString();

};                     
#endif
```

Proprietario.h

```
#ifndef __PROPRIETARIO__
#define __PROPRIETARIO__

#include <iostream>
#include "motocicleta.h"
#include "caminhao.h"
#include "carreta.h"
#include "carro.h"

using namespace std;

class Carro;
class Carreta;
class Caminhao;
class Motocicleta;

class Proprietario{
protected:
  string nome;
  string cpf;
  Motocicleta* mMoto;
  Caminhao* mCaminhao;
  Carreta* mCarreta;
  Carro* mCarro;
};
```

Veiculo.h:

```
#ifndef __VEICULO__
#define __VEICULO__
#include <iostream>
#include "proprietario.h"
#include "roda.h"
#include "motor.h"

using namespace std;
class Motor;
class Proprietario;
class Veiculo{
protected:
  int nPassageiros;
  string modelo;
  string placa;
  int aFabricacao;
  Proprietario* pai;
  Roda* rodas;
  Motor* mMotor;
  int nRodas;
  };
```

I removed the methods, because if i added those the question will be to long, sorry, the code is in PT-BR. I saw that the problem is usually is forward declaration. But i cannot find out the problem, i looked in so many forums but i cannot find out the problem..

Someone can help me?

Need any other part of the code?

Comment: Which line is which line? Post the code at the specified line in the error message

Comment: those cpp's are huge, i'll add only the call ^^

Comment: In your previous question, I answered that you should remove the includes and leave only forward declarations where possible. It seems to me like you're looking for someone to take your code, fix it, and post back the corrected version.

Comment: Post the contents of `proprietario.cpp`. The error here is "`invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Motocicleta’`", "`forward declaration of ‘struct Motocicleta’`" is just a helpful note (which your compiler has put in with the error to help you).

Comment: I solved the problem.. i needed to add those headers in the cpp file.. THANKS

Comment: don't worry, cause @LuchianGrigore says that to everybody: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065695/include-directive-messing-up-with-the-program

Comment: @PatrickBassut I don't follow...

Comment: @demonofnight:You could have posted the contents of proprietario.cpp for the viewers to have more understanding on this problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Proprietario.cpp on line 36 you do something with class Motocicleta, without including full class declaration first (you only have a forward declaration).

Answer (score 3):

Either the header declaring a class should be included (`#include "xxx.h"`) *or* the class should be forward-declared (`class xxx;`). You seem to be doing both in your headers, leading to forward-declaration *after* true declaration, which is probably the cause of said troubles.

Answer (score 2):

You have more `#include`s than you need.  If you only need a forward declaration, there is no need to include the header file as well.  For example, in Proprietario.h, you only use pointers to `Motocicleta`, `Caminhao`, `Carreta` and `Carro` so all you need is the forward declarations, you don't need to `#include "motocicleta.h"` so you can remove that.

This doesn't quite explain the error though.  I think if you simplify your headers, it will be easier to track down the error.  Without seeing proprietario.cpp and whatever you removed from the headers you listed in your question, I can't be too sure about the cause of the error.